# Backbone + indexdb

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, javascript-framework, indexeddb

I am using Backbone.js for the first time (as well as the MVC stuff) to develop a web app that makes use of the IndexedDB for storage of files, and was wondering if it makes sense to  put the database interactions in a Model or is this overkill?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be part of the Model, as that's what handles your storage interaction. Before you go about creating your own checkout the existing [backbone indexeddb adapter](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter).